# .Net Core - Passing Input Controller value into ViewComponent/Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I am pretty sure if this was in a form I could simply just put
`var name = this.Request.Form["txtName"];`
To get the value in the action. But since its not a form I am just trying to get this value of a hidden input in my controller so I can use it in the method.
I have tried passing in the name of the input in the action parameters using a session/tempdata but that does not work because in a new tab it then uses this same value so I have to have a set value saved on the page and use that value in the controller.
I thought I could do a querystring but also I have not had luck passing this into the action.
Here is what I have.

```
Html
        <input id="txthguid" name="txthguid" type="hidden" value="@TempData["guid"]" />
        
        <input asp-for="TabGuid" type="hidden" value="@TempData["guid"]" />
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("DataPage", Model)

View Compnent 
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string sessionID, object txthguid, LNPartVM model)
        {
            if (TempData != null)
            {
                TempData.Keep();
            }

            List<LNPartVM> lstData = null;
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(txthguid.ToString());
                _logger.LogInformation(TempData["guid"].ToString());



                var jsonResponse = "";
                //string sessionID = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Id;
                //string sessionID = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("sGUID");
                var tabGuid = Request.Query["txthguid"];
                _logger.LogInformation(tabGuid);
```

Comment: What stops you using form?

Comment: nothing will that work? I wrap <form> around the inputs and in my viewcomponent can I somehow get those values when the HTML loads? it doesnt use a button click it just loads the view component and I would like to get the values in an input control I tried                 var ed = this.Request.Form["TabGuid"];   but this did not work...

Comment: You need to create a model and send it to the view I suggest you read up on MVC basics.

Comment: `I thought I could do a querystring but also I have not had luck passing this into the action. `I'm afraid not,you could set `@TempData["guid"]` into model.